# Size of graphics view in Qt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have created a graphics view using design mode in the main window using QtCreator. I want to use the geometry size of the graphics view.

I did this using ui->graphicsview->width() and ui->graphicsview->height() for width and height respectively.

I want to create a bounding rectangle of same dimensions. I did it using following code:

```
QRectF line::boundingRect() const
{
return QRectF(0,0,ui->graphicsview->width(),ui->graphicsview->height());
}
```

Alas, this doesn't work. The application finishes unexpectedly. How do I implement it correctly?

Comment: can you please highlight briefly what/why are you trying to achieve ? Also can you do debugs of the graphic views top, left, height, width. That may help explain some things

Comment: I want to create a bounding rectangle whose size is equal to the size of graphics view created in design mode. I used qDebug in line class but didn't work. qDebug works in main window class in whose ui file graphics view was created.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work ? Was there no output of the qDebug ? May be some more code snippets are required to understand the problem.

Comment: No there is no output for qDebug in line class. Well, I have pasted code here: http://pastebin.com/Jki7hEg3  I am sorry for the inconvenience to you due to not so clear description of my problem!

Comment: Where in the control flow is this function called? If you call it before you set up the UI, then it will crash instantly.

Comment: You don't need a custom class if you just need to draw a rectangle. Use `QGraphicsScene::addRect` instead. You should read documentation and examples to get basic understanding of the graphics view framework.